# Convert Array into an Observable array

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, observablecollection, observable, ko.observablearray

I have an `array` which comes from my **Model** into a **View**,I want to convert this array having name `FilterListOptions` into an `observable type Array` ? How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to initialize observable array with simple array?

Comment: I want to convert the array which my model send to view in to observable array.

Comment: You can pass array to the call of ko.observableArray to initialize it with it. ko.observableArray(arr)

Comment: can you give me Explicit Code

Comment: var arr = ["Test", "Test2"];
var obsArr = ko.observableArray(arr);

Comment: You want all it's properties to be observables?

Answer (score 0):

Knockout models should have observableArray (not array) if you want to have full bindings.
But if you want limited binding you can use simple objects:

From value-binding documentation:
If you use value to link a form element to a non-observable property (e.g., a plain old string, or an arbitrary JavaScript expression), KO will do the following:

- If you reference a simple property, i.e., it is just a regular
  property on your view model, KO will set the form element’s initial
  state to the property value, and when the form element is edited, KO
  will write the changes back to your property. It cannot detect when
  the property changes (because it isn’t observable), so this is only a
  1-way binding.

  If you reference something that is not a simple property, e.g., the
  result of a function call or comparison operation, KO will set the
  form element’s initial state to that value, but it will not be able
  to write any changes back when the user edits the form element. In
  this case it’s a one-time-only value setter, not an ongoing binding
  that reacts to changes.

To simply wrap array by observable array do it in the following way:

```
var some_object = { myarray: [1,2,3] };
some_object.myarray = ko.observableArray(some_object.myarray);
```

Comment: Are you seeing any issue?

Comment: It must work... Obviously you have some troubles with another parts of your code. So maybe it is better to provide more details.